# How to submit a form results to a table on another page?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, html-table

I would like to know how to submit a form on one page of my website and then have the form info be posted to a table on another page of my website. Here is the page of the form that would be filled out:

[image]

and then here is the page that I want that data to fill into:

[image]

I would want the form info that was submitted to be posted in the same categories in the table. For example, in the form it says "Town". Then in the table in the second picture it says "Town" I would want the data to be the same categories and also have it so the most recent form submission is at the top of the table. Here is the form html code:

```
<div align="center">
<form id="dispatch" name="dispatch" method="post" action="index.html">
  <table width="801" height="420" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">TOWN</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="town" id="town" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">LOCATION</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="location" id="location" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">INCIDENT TYPE</td>
      <td><select name="incident_type" size="1" id="incident_type">
        <option selected="selected"></option>
         <option value=\"Fire alarm \"> Fire alarm </option>              <option value=\"Reported structure fire\"> Reported structure fire </option>              <option value=\"Working structure fire\"> Working structure fire </option>              <option value=\"MVA with no injuries\"> MVA with no injuries </option>              <option value=\"MVA with injuries\"> MVA with injuries </option>              <option value=\"MVA with unknown injuries\"> MVA with unknown injuries </option>              <option value=\"Train accident\"> Train accident </option>              <option value=\"Traffic alert\"> Traffic alert </option>              <option value=\"Shooting\"> Shooting </option>              <option value=\"Stabbing\"> Stabbing </option>              <option value=\"Vehicle fire\"> Vehicle fire </option>              <option value=\"Traumatic injury\"> Traumatic injury </option>              <option value=\"PNB\"> PNB </option>              <option value=\"Utility pole\/hazard\"> Utility pole\/hazard </option>              <option value=\"Natural gas investigation\"> Natural gas investigation </option>              <option value=\"Odor investigation\"> Odor investigation </option>              <option value=\"Carbon monoxide poisoning \"> Carbon monoxide poisoning </option>              <option value=\"Brush fire\"> Brush fire </option>              <option value=\"Outside fire\"> Outside fire </option>              <option value=\"Oil spill \"> Oil spill </option>              <option value=\"Armed robbery\"> Armed robbery </option>              <option value=\"Police vehicle chase\"> Police vehicle chase </option>              <option value=\"Bomb threat\"> Bomb threat </option>              <option value=\"Officer injured\"> Officer injured </option>              <option value=\"Aircraft down\"> Aircraft down </option>              <option value=\"Hostage situation \"> Hostage situation </option>              <option value=\"Officer needs help\"> Officer needs help </option>              <option value=\"Water rescue\"> Water rescue </option>              <option value=\"Technical rescue\"> Technical rescue </option>              <option value=\"Haz-Mat incident\"> Haz-Mat incident </option>              <option value=\"Mass casualty\"> Mass casualty </option>              <option value=\"Tornado touchdown\"> Tornado touchdown </option>              <option value=\"Tornado warning \"> Tornado warning </option>              <option value=\"Search and rescue\"> Search and rescue </option> 
        <option>Working Fire</option>
                <option>Working Still Alarm</option>
                <option>Full Still</option>
                <option>Code 3</option>
                <option>Code 4</option>
                <option>General Alarm</option>
                <option>Special Alarm</option>
                <option>Box Alarm</option>
                <option>Box Alarm COQ Only</option>
                <option>Box Alarm Manpower Only</option>
                <option>Box Alarm Engines Only</option>
                <option>Box Alarm Tenders Only</option>
                <option>Mayday Response</option>
                <option>2nd Alarm</option>
                <option>2nd Alarm COQ Only</option>
                <option>2nd Alarm Manpower Only</option>
                <option>2nd Alarm Engines Only</option>
                <option>2nd Alarm Tenders Only</option>
                <option>3rd Alarm</option>
                <option>3rd Alarm COQ Only</option>
                <option>3rd Alarm Manpower Only</option>
                <option>3rd Alarm Engines Only</option>
                <option>3rd Alarm Tenders Only</option>
                <option>4th Alarm</option>
                <option>4th Alarm COQ Only</option>
                <option>4th Alarm Manpower Only</option>
                <option>4th Alarm Engines Only</option>
                <option>4th Alarm Tenders Only</option>
                <option>5th Alarm</option>
                <option>5th Alarm COQ Only</option>
                <option>5th Alarm Manpower Only</option>
                <option>5th Alarm Engines Only</option>
                <option>5th Alarm Tenders Only</option>
                <option>5th + 1 Special</option>
                <option>5th + 2 Specials</option>
                <option>5th + 3 Specials</option>
                <option>5th + 4 Specials</option>
                <option>6th Alarm Tenders Only</option>
                <option>Interdivisional Box</option>
                <option>Brush Box Alarm</option>
                <option>2nd Alarm Brush Box</option>
                <option>3rd Alarm Brush Box</option>
                <option>4th Alarm Brush Box</option>
                <option>5th Alarm Brush Box</option>
                <option value="Interdiv Brush Box">Interdivisional Brush</option>
                <option>Disaster Box Alarm</option>
                <option>2nd Alarm Disaster Box</option>
                <option>3rd Alarm Disaster Box</option>
                <option>4th Alarm Disaster Box</option>
                <option>5th Alarm Disaster Box</option>
                <option value="Interdivisional Disaster Box">Interdiv Disaster Box</option>
                <option value="Dive Box Alarm - Advisors Only">Dive Box Alarm - Adv</option>
                <option>Dive Box Alarm</option>
                <option>2nd Alarm Dive Box</option>
                <option>Interdivisional Dive Box</option>
                <option>EMS Box Alarm</option>
                <option>2nd Alarm EMS Box</option>
                <option>3rd Alarm EMS Box</option>
                <option>4th Alarm EMS Box</option>
                <option>5th Alarm EMS Box</option>
                <option value="Interdivisional EMS Box Alarm">Interdiv EMS Box</option>
                <option value="2nd Alarm Interdivisional EMS Box">2nd Alm Interdiv EMS Box</option>
                <option value="3rd Alarm Interdivisional EMS Box">3rd Alm Interdiv EMS Box</option>
                <option>Life Safety Box Alarm</option>
                <option>2nd Alarm Life Safety Box</option>
                <option>3rd Alarm Life Safety Box</option>
                <option>4th Alarm Life Safety Box</option>
                <option>5th Alarm Life Safety Box</option>
                <option value="Interdivisional Life Safety Box Alarm">Interdiv Life Safety Box</option>
                <option value="HazMat Response">HazMat (Non-Box)</option>
                <option value="HazMat Box - Advisors Only">HazMat Box - Adv Only</option>
                <option>HazMat Box Alarm</option>
                <option value="HazMat Box Alarm 2nd Team">Hazmat Bx Alm 2nd Team</option>
                <option value="2nd Alarm HazMat Box">2nd Alarm HazMat Box</option>
                <option value="Interdivisional HazMat Box">Interdiv HazMat Box</option>
                <option value="Investigators Box - Advisors Only">Invest Box - Adv Only</option>
                <option>Investigators Box Alarm</option>
                <option value="2nd Alarm Investigators Box">2nd Alarm Invest Box</option>
                <option value="Interdivisional Investigators Box">Interdiv Invest Box</option>
                <option value="Tech Rescue Box - Advisors Only">Tech Resc Box-Adv Only</option>
                <option>Tech Rescue Box</option>
                <option value="Interdivisional Tech Rescue Box">Interdiv Tech Resc Box</option>
                <option>Tender Box Alarm</option>
                <option>2nd Alarm Tender Box</option>
                <option>3rd Alarm Tender Box</option>
                <option>4th Alarm Tender Box</option>
                <option>5th Alarm Tender Box</option>
                <option>6th Alarm Tender Box</option>
                <option>Tanker Plan 1 (IN)</option>
                <option>Tanker Plan 2 (IN)</option>
                <option>Tanker Plan 3 (IN)</option>
                <option>Interdivisional Tender Box</option>
                <option>Statewide Response</option>
                <option>Injured Firefighter</option>
                <option>Injured Firefighters</option>
                <option>FF LODD</option>
                <option>PO LODD</option>
      </select></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">TIME/DATE</td>
      <td><input name="time_date" type="text" id="time_date" maxlength="60" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="138" align="center"><p>ADMIN </p></td>
      <td width="228"><input name="admin" type="text" id="admin" size="4" maxlength="4" /></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /> 
      <input type="reset" name="button2" id="button2" value="Reset" />
  </p>
</form>
</div>
```

This is the table:

```
    <div align="center">
  <form action="" method="get">
  <table width="968" height="248" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" rules="rows" id="incidents" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:left;">
    <tr style="color:White;background-color:#5D7B9D;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;">
      <th scope="col">TOWN</th>
      <th scope="col">LOCATION</th>
      <th scope="col">INCIDENT TYPE</th>
      <th scope="col">TIME/DATE</th>
      <th scope="col">ADMIN</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;font-weight:bold;">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color:#284775;background-color:White;font-weight:bold;">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;font-weight:bold;">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;font-weight:bold;">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;font-weight:bold;">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Forms post to where their `action` tells them.  Are you trying to achieve something different?

Comment: You are going to need to add some PHP code (as you have tagged PHP) in the table to get the data appearing. Looking at your table though, you want multiple rows so you likely want to keep a copy of the posted data (either as a file somewhere or in a database).

Comment: I want something like what this person asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555796/how-to-create-a-table-in-which-rows-are-filled-in-when-a-user-submits-a-form

Comment: Turnerj, is there a way I can do that in PHP then?

Comment: you still need help with this?/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't know any code in php, so here is the code to post your data to next page, but you need to install wamp or xampp to run a php code.

```
<form id="dispatch" name="dispatch" method="post" action="nextpage.php">
```

in your nextpage.php use this code to insert it to your table

```
<?php
//because you use method post you can access your form value by using this code
$town = $_POST['town'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$time= $_POST['incident_type'];
$admin = $_POST['admin'];
?>

  <div align="center">
  <form action="" method="get">
 <table width="968" height="248" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0"  rules="rows" id="incidents" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:left;">
  <tr style="color:White;background-color:#5D7B9D;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;">
  <th scope="col">TOWN</th>
  <th scope="col">LOCATION</th>
  <th scope="col">INCIDENT TYPE</th>
  <th scope="col">TIME/DATE</th>
  <th scope="col">ADMIN</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;font-weight:bold;">
  <?php
      echo "<td>". $town."</td>";
      echo "<td>". $location."</td>";
      echo "<td>". $time."</td>";
      echo "<td>". $admin ."</td>";
   ?>
  </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my form page is dispatch.html and then my table page is index.html. What would I do then?

Comment: you can't use php code if your extension is html, rename your second page as index.php or nextpage.php

Comment: wait, do you have wamp server or xampp server?

Comment: Yes I do have WAMP server installed. I will let you know how it works.

Comment: Where should I put the second piece of code you put above?

Comment: it means the variable $town is undefined, did you put this code? `$town = $_POST['town'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$time= $_POST['incident_type'];
$admin = $_POST['admin'];` if you do, then check this <input type="text" name="town" id="town" /> did you really put the town as name? if not put name='town', but if you do, check this `<form id="dispatch" name="dispatch" method="post" action="index.html">` make sure the method is post or try POST instead. That should do

Comment: I am kind of confused now. I have uploaded my two files dispatch.php and index.php here: https://www.mediafire.com/?qb8xho99zi8adv0,zd7474d5e5720xp and if you wouldn't mind looking through them real quick to see if I did it right or not because I'm pretty sure I'm not doing it right. Thank you.

Comment: I fixed it. The id was not assigned to the labels in dispatch.php. Thanks so much for the help! I have a couple more minor issues that I should be able to solve, but I may need your help later. Thank you again for all the help you provided!

Comment: That's fine, im glad to help

Comment: One more thing. When I submit it, the table only holds one submission at a time, then when I go to submit another, the new one is there and the old one is gone. I want it to add another row each time there is a new submission so I can see all the submissions.

Comment: In that case, You need to use database. do you know how to create database and table in wamp or xampp?

Comment: No I do not know how to do that.

Comment: That's a big problem. You need database to save it

Comment: Can't I just store all on the same page? I'm fine if the page is really long with all the responses going down the page. I want them all to be shown in that table.

Comment: wait i'll try to save it in array

Comment: i can't save it in array, maybe ill help you to create database, goto browser type localhost/phpmyadmin, if cannot go to this page type 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin

Comment: create database name it anything you want and after you create, create table name it also anything you want and make it 5 column for the town location etc. and their data is make it text for now. That's all you need to do

Comment: did you see the name? put the like town location etc, and in type, select text

Comment: then what after that when I saved it?

Comment: do this code in your index`mysql_query('localhost','root',"");` `//the first parameter is your server second is your username and last is your password` `mysql_select_db("database name");` `$result= mysql_query("select * from your_table_name");` while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result){
//replace this to your old php code
echo "<td>" .$row['town'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row['location'] ."</td>";
echo //do the other here

}

that's all

Comment: I'm actually just coming back to this now, and I have one more question about that. Where exactly should I put this in my index.html? In the head, the body, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way would be to insert data into your database from the first page this way you can query it to get the data you need in the other page.

You other option is too use session if you don't mind about persisting data.

Comment: I wouldn't want to have them insert data straight to the table. Is there no way I can have it submit from the form page and have it submit the form data into the table automatically?

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can carry the post values into sessions. Or you can use the post array directly to populate your table

Comment: Can you give me the code and tell me what to do? I am a beginner at this stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Damn i wish but im on my phone check codeslayer answer that should do. If not let me know

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, whenever you get to a computer or have time if you could please give me the code for it. It would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Yes sure no problem on my way home

Comment: I just came back to this project, can you still help me?