# Form Data to a Table With a Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

A few months ago I was working on a project and posted it here for help: [How to submit a form results to a table on another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839830/how-to-submit-a-form-results-to-a-table-on-another-page). Now I need help again. If you go down to this comment on my previous question (see comment here: [How to submit a form results to a table on another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839830/how-to-submit-a-form-results-to-a-table-on-another-page#comment40504329_25839932)), this user was helping me and I got everything figured out except the the database. When I submit my form, the page loads with a blank table. How can I get it so when I enter the form information and submit it, it then goes to the 2nd page (see below) and puts the data into the table? I had it working before, before I incorporated the database in it.

Here is my code for the page called dispatch.php (which is the the form page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>LMCS CAD - Live Incident Status</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://tabstart.com/system/icons/14476/original/favicon.ico?1306467370" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size: 12px;">



<div align="center">
    <h1><img src="assests/lmcslogo.png" alt="York County 911 - Live Incident Status"/></h1>
    <p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
document.write(Date());
    </script></p>
    <h1><a href="index.php">Home</a> | <a href="dispatch.php">Dispatch An Incident</a> | <a href="help.php">Help</a></h1>
    <div></div>
</div>



<div align="center">
<form id="dispatch" name="dispatch" method="post" action="indexcad.php">
  <table width="801" height="420" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" id="town">TOWN</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="town" id="town" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" id="location">LOCATION</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="location" id="location" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" id="incident_type">INCIDENT TYPE</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="incident_type" id="incident_type" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" id="time_date">TIME/DATE</td>
      <td><input name="time_date" type="text" id="time_date" maxlength="60" /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="138" align="center"><p id="admin">ADMIN </p></td>
      <td width="228"><input name="admin" type="text" id="admin" size="4" maxlength="4" /></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /> 
      <input type="reset" name="button2" id="button2" value="Reset" />
  </p>
</form>

</div>




<p>&nbsp;</p>
<hr />
<p style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">&copy; 2014 Lake McHenry County Scanner</p>


</body>
</html>
```

And here is my page called indexcad.php (which is the page the form data comes up on):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
//because you use method post you can access your form value by using this code
$town = $_POST['town'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$incident_type= $_POST['incident_type'];
$time_date= $_POST['time_date'];
$admin = $_POST['admin'];

$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Database error"); 
mysql_select_db('mydatabase', $db);  
$result= mysql_query("select * from cad"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
?>

<head>
    <title>LMCS CAD</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div align="center">
  <form action="" method="get">
 <table width="968" height="248" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0"  rules="rows" id="incidents" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:left;">
  <tr style="color:White;background-color:#5D7B9D;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;">
  <th scope="col">TOWN</th>
  <th scope="col">LOCATION</th>
  <th scope="col">INCIDENT TYPE</th>
  <th scope="col">TIME/DATE</th>
  <th scope="col">ADMIN</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;font-weight:bold;">
  <?php
      //replace this to your old php code 
echo "<td>" .$row['town'] ."</td>"; 
echo "<td>" .$row['location'] ."</td>"; 
echo "<td>" .$row['incident_type'] ."</td>"; 
echo "<td>" .$row['time_date'] ."</td>"; 
echo "<td>" .$row['admin'] ."</td>"; 
   ?>
  </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this comment will be done, so why not by me :-) forget mysql_... functions, use mysqli_... or pdo class, for safety reasons.

Comment: then first of all: is your connection ok and does your request bring data? Try this `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {print_r($row);}` to test this first point. If this is ok then let's see how to make a valid while loop in the right place...

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, although there were no errors on the page. But when I tried it and replaced the "mysql_" with "mysqli_", then it gave me a errors on the page. But without the "mysqli_" and just "musql_", no errors were given, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general shape of your script could look like this (i didn't look precisely if smthg wrong in your code, just reorganized it a bit...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LMCS CAD</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div align="center">
  <form action="" method="get">
 <table width="968" height="248" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0"  rules="rows" id="incidents" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:left;">
  <tr style="color:White;background-color:#5D7B9D;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;">
  <th scope="col">TOWN</th>
  <th scope="col">LOCATION</th>
  <th scope="col">INCIDENT TYPE</th>
  <th scope="col">TIME/DATE</th>
  <th scope="col">ADMIN</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;font-weight:bold;">
    <?php
    $town = $_POST['town'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $incident_type= $_POST['incident_type'];
    $time_date= $_POST['time_date'];
    $admin = $_POST['admin'];

    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Database error"); 
    mysqli_select_db($db, 'mydatabase');  
    $result= mysqli_query($db, "select * from cad"); 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<td>" .$row['town'] ."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" .$row['location'] ."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" .$row['incident_type'] ."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" .$row['time_date'] ."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" .$row['admin'] ."</td>"; 
    }
    ?>
  </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: also try to add this at the beginning of your script (before `&lt;!doctype...>` (to make sure you see all error/warning/notice messages): `<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>`
Remove it when you are not debugging any more.

Comment: This is what happens now (I replaced my "mysql_" to "mysqli_" and copy/pasted the orgranized code that you did into it), it shows these errors on the page when I try submitting it: http://i.imgur.com/I7w3otI.png

Comment: add parameter `$db` to mysqli_select_db() and mysqli_query() calls (see edited answer above).

Comment: Thank you, that solved the error messages, but now the form data still doesn't go into the table on the next page.

Comment: please echo the `print_r(..)` as i proposed above, so you can see if your query give you some data... and maybe `echo mysqli_num_rows($result);` too, to see how many entries found, as well as `echo mysqli_error($db);` to get info on encountered errors on mysql side...

Comment: but what you're trying to fill in the table is data extracted from your DB, it has nothing to do with the form... I'm not sure you're really clear about what you want to do, nor with what your are actually doing, so it seems difficult to help you further.

Comment: You probably want a form that gets data from users, then a script that saves it to your DB, then another script that displays the previously saved data. Make some searches on how to insert data in a DB, and how to select it later. Googling "save form data to mysql" brings you howto's like: http://php.about.com/od/phpbasics/ss/mysql_files.htm#step-heading or http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-MySQL-Creating-Form-Insert-Data-P280.html. Take time to learn, try, understand and Stackoverflow will surely help you solving problems. But Stackoverflow won't do it all for you...

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't explain it right, but yes, I want it the user to submit the data via the form and then have it save to the the database. After that, have it inserted to the table. I will take a look at those links you shared and let you know if I have problems. Thank you.